# Testing form action on submit with sinon and jasmine

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, jasmine, sinon

I try to verify that a proper form action is performed when the submit button is clicked. I run the tests with Karma (formerly testacular) in Chrome and i use `sinon` to create a fake server to capture the POST request. It looks like it is not captured

Form

```
<form action="/authenticate_open_id" method="POST">
<label>Or sign up with:</label>
<input type="hidden" name="openid_identifier" value="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id"/>
<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="/"/>
<input id="signup_with_google" type="submit" value="Google Account"/></form><
```

Test code

```
server = sinon.fakeServer.create()
server.autoRespond = true
server.respondWith 'POST', '/authenticate_open_id', [302, {}, '']

view.$el.find('#signup_with_google').click()
waitsFor ->
    server.requests.length > 0
, 'server has not been called', 100                    
runs ->
    console.log 'server', server.requests
```

The fake server never captures that request (but similar code works for ajax initiated requests). However i get an error in the chrome browser that runs the test suite

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:9876/authenticate_open_id
```

, so it looks like some request has been done, but the fake server could not capture it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cant work as the fake server only works for ajax requests. The only thing the fake server does is to mock XmlHttpRequest object and call the passed success/error functions. So in your case clicking the button will end in a page reload with the new your post url.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. I'd guess this type of form action is not so testable then.